# macOS Realm Browser requests encryption key to open after upgrading realm 1.13.0 to 2.0.0?

Tags: realm, realm-browser

When I close app in iOS simulator and use **Realm Browser** to open **database.realm** it asks me to enter encryption key to open?

I had to roll-back to **realm 1.13.0**

Anyone else run into this?  Any solutions?

- Realm Browser: macOS Version 2.1.12 (96)
- Target: react native on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm JavaScript v2.0.0 has a newer file format, and so requires a newer version of Realm Browser, v3.0.0 or newer, in order to open the files. We're currently waiting for the new version of Realm Browser to make its way through the App Store update system. In the mean time, you can [download the new version from our GitHub release page](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/v3.0.0).

Comment: I updated to Realm 2.0.0 and Realm Browser 3.0.0 and all is good again.  Even better, now I can open the database.realm file in Realm Browser without having to close the iOS app running in the iOS simulator!